# Rewriting exponential expressions - when subtracting expressions where does a 1 come from?

Tags: exponential-function

I'm trying to do problems on Khan Academy in the area of 'rewriting exponential expressions.' I got one wrong and the answer is shown as:

= $3^x - 3^x/9$

= $3^x (1 - 1/9)$

= $8/9 * 3^x$

I don't understand step 2... where did the $1 - 1/9$ come from?

Thank you

Comment: Factored out the 3^x. To check, multiply back.

Comment: it comes from factoring

Comment: $$ \boxed{ ax + ay = a(x+y)  }$$

Comment: thank you both! now i see